# Microsoft Teams Bot keeps asking user consent even after approval

Tags: c#, botframework, microsoft-teams, chatbot

I have set up a bot using .Net 6 with Microsoft Bot Framework and added SSO for Teams according to the following manual:

[SSO Documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/bots/how-to/authentication/auth-aad-sso-bots)

In my bot, I have a three simple commands (Hi, Hello and Help). The Bot is asking for consent and permissions even though it's being successfully accepted in the first approval.

I'm sending a sign in invoke card using the following:

```
private async Task SendSigninInvoKeCard(ITurnContext turnContext, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
{
    try
    {
        _logger.LogInformation("Sending signin invoke card");
        var attachment = new Microsoft.Bot.Schema.Attachment
        {
            Content = new OAuthCard
            {
                TokenExchangeResource = new TokenExchangeResource
                {
                    Id = Guid.NewGuid().ToString()
                }
            },
            ContentType = OAuthCard.ContentType,
        };
        var activity = MessageFactory.Attachment(attachment);

        // NOTE: This activity needs to be sent in the 1:1 conversation between the bot and the user. 
        // If the bot supports group and channel scope, this code should be updated to send the request to the 1:1 chat. 
        await turnContext.SendActivityAsync(activity, cancellationToken);
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        _logger.LogError(e, "Failed to send signin invoke card");
        await turnContext.SendActivityAsync(MessageFactory.Text($"Please try again later."), cancellationToken);
    }
}
```

And handling the invoke activity as the following:

```
protected override async Task<InvokeResponse> OnInvokeActivityAsync(ITurnContext<IInvokeActivity> turnContext, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
{
    try
    {
        if (turnContext.Activity.Name == SignInConstants.TokenExchangeOperationName && turnContext.Activity.ChannelId == Microsoft.Bot.Connector.Channels.Msteams)
        {
            await _tokenExchangeHelper.ShouldProcessTokenExchange(turnContext, cancellationToken);
            return new InvokeResponse() { Status = 200 };
        }
        else
        {
            return await base.OnInvokeActivityAsync(turnContext, cancellationToken);
        }
    }
    catch (InvokeResponseException e)
    {
        return e.CreateInvokeResponse();
    }
}
```

As for the `TokenExchangeHelper` it's running as follow:

```
public async Task<bool> ShouldProcessTokenExchange(ITurnContext turnContext, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
{
    if (turnContext.Activity.Name != SignInConstants.TokenExchangeOperationName)
    {
        throw new InvalidOperationException("Only 'signin/tokenExchange' invoke activities can be procssed by TokenExchangeHelper.");
    }

    if (!await ExchangedTokenAsync(turnContext, cancellationToken))
    {
        return false;
    }

    var storeItem = new TokenStoreItem
    {
        ETag = (turnContext.Activity.Value as JObject).Value<string>("id")
    };

    var storeItems = new Dictionary<string, object> { { TokenStoreItem.GetStorageKey(turnContext), storeItem } };
    try
    {
        await _storage.WriteAsync(storeItems, cancellationToken).ConfigureAwait(false);
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
        when (ex.Message.StartsWith("Etag conflict"))
    {
        return false;
    }

    return true;
}

private async Task<bool> ExchangedTokenAsync(ITurnContext turnContext, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
{
    TokenResponse tokenExchangeResponse = null;
    var tokenExchangeRequest = ((JObject)turnContext.Activity.Value)?.ToObject<TokenExchangeInvokeRequest>();

    try
    {
        var userTokenClient = turnContext.TurnState.Get<UserTokenClient>();
        tokenExchangeResponse = await userTokenClient.ExchangeTokenAsync(
            turnContext.Activity.From.Id,
            _oAuthConnectionName,
            turnContext.Activity.ChannelId,
            new TokenExchangeRequest { Token = tokenExchangeRequest.Token },
            cancellationToken);
    }
    catch
    {
        // Ignore Exceptions
        // If token exchange failed for any reason, tokenExchangeResponse above stays null , and hence we send back a failure invoke response to the caller.
    }

    if (tokenExchangeResponse == null || string.IsNullOrEmpty(tokenExchangeResponse.Token))
    {
        await turnContext.SendActivityAsync(
            new Activity
            {
                Type = ActivityTypesEx.InvokeResponse,
                Value = new InvokeResponse
                {
                    Status = (int)HttpStatusCode.PreconditionFailed,
                    Body = new TokenExchangeInvokeResponse
                    {
                        Id = tokenExchangeRequest.Id,
                        ConnectionName = _oAuthConnectionName,
                        FailureDetail = "The bot is unable to exchange token. Proceed with regular login.",
                    },
                },
            }, cancellationToken);

        return false;
    }
    else
    {
        turnContext.TurnState[nameof(TokenExchangeInvokeRequest)] = tokenExchangeRequest;
        turnContext.TurnState[nameof(TokenResponse)] = tokenExchangeResponse;
        var userStateAccessors = _userState.CreateProperty<UserInfo>(nameof(UserInfo));
        var userInfo = await userStateAccessors.GetAsync(turnContext, () => new UserInfo(), cancellationToken);
        userInfo.Token = tokenExchangeResponse.Token;
        await _userState.SaveChangesAsync(turnContext, false, cancellationToken);
    }

    return true;
}
```

So what's wrong here?

- Is it in the way we're processing token?
- Perhaps when we should be sending the Sign in invoke cards?

Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: We have tested the following sample and its working fine at our end. We are getting only first time consent option. Could you please refer this sample and test this again?
https://github.com/OfficeDev/Microsoft-Teams-Samples/tree/main/samples/bot-conversation-sso-quickstart/csharp_dotnetcore